# Deleting the AMI Image

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

I want to delete the AMI image on the basis of its count. That is, I have defined the instance-ids in the name tag of the image, so that i can know of which instance the image is. I want to delete the images if the image count goes over 30 for that particular instance and the images deleted must be older ones not the newest ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this:

```
from boto.ec2 import connect_to_region
images = sorted(connect_to_region('us-west-1').get_all_images(owners='self'))
for candidates in images[30:]:
    candidates.deregister()
```

assuming your .boto/boto.cfg is setup with your keys

**update**

If you want to do it by the date and not just order of AMIs (sorry I missed that) then you will need a custom script, something like:

```
from boto.ec2 import connect_to_region
images = (connect_to_region('us-west-1').get_all_images(owners='amazon'))
amis = {}
amis = dict([(image.id, image.creationDate) for image in images if 'ami' in image.id ])
candidates = [x for (x,y) in sorted(amis.items(), key=lambda (k,v): v)][:30]
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
len(candidates)
for image in images:
    print image.id
    if str(image.id) in candidates:
        print "try to remove"
        image.deregister()
    else:
        print "current 30"
```

Comment: yeah but it sorts the images by the image ids, but i want to sort by their creation date.

Comment: I have tried your updated script and is working fine and alternatively i would suggest you to look into the scripts in the link which i have posted.

Comment: Thanks -  if you feel that this answers your question - feel free to mark it so

Answer (score 0):

It looks quite custom.. so a custom script would be able to solve it. Using CLI commands like describe-images.
You should also store the creation of the image as a tag.

I assume you don't have that much images ( thousands) so you can easily build an array about the different images, count them and select the latest one in O(n) time. Then you need to call the deregister-image command.

The script can run periodically.

The best would be to run it as a lambda function, but it is may not ready for it because of the lack of triggering. ( No cron style trigger at the moment.) But you may can trigger the function with the creation of a new AMI.